# Can PlayStation Mobile questions be asked here?

Tags: discussion

PSM is a platform for indie development on the PS Vita and PlayStation Certified Android devices. You code in C# using what it seems to be a heavily modified version of mono, with a rather minimal API to control some of the features in the PS Vita.

They also support publishing to their online store, with a yearly payment required.

So, to me, this looks very similar in idea and scope to Microsoft's XNA.

I haven't yet seen any PSM questions in here, and I would like to know if it would be okay to ask some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be alright to ask playstation mobile questions here.

Comment: Well, I made my first question. Let's hope we can steal some people from the official PSM forums.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you're not breaking any developer NDAs there's no problem with it.

Comment: I heard iOS development requires signing an NDA. Does that mean iOS questions are technically forbidden?

Comment: Considering most of their docs are publicly available: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/, no

Comment: @PandaPajama: Note: the notice about NDAs is for *your* benefit, not ours. You're the one who would be in trouble for breaking NDAs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Nobody said PSM has NDA requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the others have already noted - it should be fine. I just tried finding a PSM tag, but it doesn't exist however. It would be a good idea if one of the higher rep users could create it.